# Java Stream and foreach

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of maps. The map holds two values "key" and "value" I have to filter out specific values from that list. So I am iterating through the list and if the map has the key that I want, then I take that value and set it in another pojo.

```
{ 
teams=["
{key=NAME, value="ANKIT"}, 
{key=START_DATE, value=2016-09-01}
}
String START_DATE = "START_DATE";
STRING NAME = "NAME";
```

I have multiple conditions to check. I am doing this using `foreach`. Can this be done using Java 8 `stream()`.

```
teamList.forEach(
team -> {
    if (NAME.equals(team.get("key"))) {
        team.setName(team.get("value"));
    } else if (START_DATE.equals(team.get("key"))) {
      team.setEndDate(LocalDate.parse(team.get("value")));
    } 
});
```

Comment: why do you want to do that by streams?

Comment: Even before we get into the subject of streams... what on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a list of maps. The map holds two values "key" and "value" I have to filter out specific values from that list. So I am iterating through the list and if the map has the key that I want, then I take that value and set it in another pojo.

Comment: `The map holds two values "key" and "value" `, usually a map will hold multiple keys and values, you can get a `.keySet()` or an `.entrySet()` from a map and stream them

Comment: Can you give an example

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Java 8 new features to replace your old Java code. I think as everyone was trying to point out that fact what you are trying is not a recommended use of Java 8 streams.

Best practice in Java 8 is to avoid state-full operations. *(That means, you are modifying an existing object. Here in this case, you are setting data to a object that resides in memory which had created earlier)*

If you still wants to write this simple logic using Java 8 streams, below you can see the POJO class and the main method that sets the Data to that object.

```
public class POJO {

    private Integer age;
    private LocalDate birthday;

    public LocalDate getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(LocalDate birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "POJO{" +
                "age=" + age +
                ", birthday=" + birthday +
                '}';
    }
}


public class MapIteration {

    public static Map<String,Integer> ageMap = new HashMap<>();
    private static final String NAME = "Doki";
    private static final String START_DATE = "31/10/2016";
    private static POJO myDataObject = new POJO();
    private static BiConsumer<String,Integer> integerConsumer = (k, v) -> {
        try {
            if(NAME.equals(k.toString()))
              myDataObject.setAge(Integer.valueOf(v.toString()));
            else if (START_DATE.equals(LocalDate.parse(k.toString()).toString()))
                myDataObject.setBirthday(LocalDate.parse(k.toString()));
        } catch (NumberFormatException | DateTimeParseException e) {
            System.out.println("exception occurred: Because sometimes names cannot be parsed as Date formats");
        }

    };
    static{
        ageMap.put("John", 23);
        ageMap.put("Norman", 26);
        ageMap.put("Micheal", 25);
        ageMap.put("Doki", 22);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ageMap.forEach(integerConsumer);
        System.out.println(myDataObject);
    }
}
```